# Laravel update with relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I try to update a component that has a relationship, from frontend I send the correct data, but in back works to update only the main table.

[image]

```
public function updateCustomer(Request $request, Customer $customer)
{
    $customer->$customerNames->update();
    $customer->update($request->all());
    return response($customer, 200);
}
```

Comment: Could you add App\Customer  code source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$customer->account_name = $request->account_name;
$customer->sage_id = $request->sage_id;
$customer->update();

$customerNames = [];
foreach($request->customer_names as $customer_name) {
    $customerNames[] = new CustomerName(
      [
        'name' => $customer_name['name'],
        'name_type' => $customer_name['name_type'],
        'movation_date' =>  customer_name['movation_date']
      ]
    );
}

$customer->customerNames()->delete();
$customer->customerNames()->saveMany($customerNames);
//...
```

Comment: column "0" of relation "customer_names" does not exist↵LINE 1: update "customer_names" set "0" = $1 ,  this is what I got

Comment: I edited the variables, but "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Comment: Did you tired $customer_name['name'] instead of $customer_name->name ?